# Staking native assets (to stake pools)?

Tags: staking, native-assets

Is there support built in to Cardano for stake pools to receive staking of native assets?

For example, the Meld Protocol plans to include staking of Meld tokens.
Are they likely to / able to use (their own?) Cardano native stake pool(s) to achieve this?

Note that in Eth/Bsc, when we talk about staking, it means a transaction in which you loose custody of your assets because they are transferred to another wallet, the wallet of the smart contract.  Cardano is clearly different because staking (*at least, of Ada*) does not need or require this to happen.

This seems a pretty significant difference - hence, does this difference also extend to native assets and future dapp designs, and to what extent is this clear at this point?

Will stake pools take on further functionality down the road?

(I read  that hydra means a subset of stake pools will handle a channel, as a layer 2/ lightning style thing, this being a different additional role, down the road).

Of course, with Plutus, you can undoubtedly implement a staking mechanism for native assets, but I wondered whether it has been planned that the already existing stake pools can take on an additional role like this or any other.

---

I suppose the raison d'etre for what we currently call *stake pools* is (entirely) to provide the consensus layer.

Whereas, the same word, "staking", is also used in defi, when the goal is other things, completely unrelated to achieving consensus (e.g., a project wants to provide rewards for locking up tokens to decrease volatility in early stages of a project).
There seems to be a terminology challenge here - in PoW chains, the  double meaning doesn't arise. So, how are we going to handle this?
The term SPO is clearly established, so...  can't think of a good term right now...!

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely right. As a developer lot's of people ask me about staking native tokens. They get confused with staking ada (cardano stake pool), providing liquidity (like to a dex), or just simply a smart contract to vest a native token.

I still don't think native tokens should be added to stake pools at the consensus layer. I think staking through smart contracts is the best possible route and the native token creators can figure out how rewards should be generated and rewards can even be other tokens or ada.